# Is there a word to describe something new, but completely unnecesary?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe making a new thing (instead of old one), which should be way better, more innovative, but in the end remains same or even worse.

Example - car manufacturers are putting displays in place of dashboards, but those displays still show same two round dials for speedometer and tachometer (only difference - they are shown in screen instead physically with dials and needles).

Comment: Not a single word, but the phrase [**bells and whistles**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bells+and+whistles) means extra features that are added on to something that are unnecessary for its primary function.

Comment: Windows 11, iPhone 13?

Comment: _gild the lily_, perhaps.

Comment: LOL... I have one of those displays in my car - it's a *huge* improvement.

Comment: The example is poor: the displays are functionally superior as they can (and do) provide much more information than a couple of dials. Also, an improvement might benefit the *manufacturer* with no obvious advantage for the end user, for example being cheaper to make / install.

Comment: @WeatherVane The displays are also often easier to see than the regular physical dials!

Comment: My go-to example for this is the rubberized, ergonomic, comfort-grip handles now found on modern toothbrushes.  Was this really necessary?  Were people getting carpal tunnel syndrome from brushing with the old plastic-stick-and-bristles models?  I find the new ones to be inferior in every way - They're too fat to fit in many toothbrush holders, they're harder to clean, they won't lay flat on the counter, so you need both hands to apply the toothpaste.  (Anyone who's ever temporarily or permanently lost the use of a hand can tell you how much of a problem that is.)

Comment: "reinventing the wheel". Not sure it captures exactly the same sense you're looking for though.

Comment: A narrative heavy option, which is probably not very well know, is [dynamic obsolescence](https://youtu.be/j5v8D-alAKE?t=812). You could probably use the much more well known term "planned obsolescence" synonymously in most situations, which is technically incorrect, but... buzz words.

Comment: @T.Sar - they are absolutely not, the displays suffer from shit visibility in the sun. There is a reason why car enthusiasts prefer physical gauges over digital.

Comment: @Davor I have no issue at all mine. Granted, mine was modded in, so I can't speak for every gauge, but at least current screens are very pristine even on very well-lit conditions. And, about enthusiasts -  That really isn't a parameter. There are bajillions of types of car enthusiasts, with very different tastes and takes on different types of tech. My father loves low tech autos, while I personally love the more cyberpunky ones. It varies a lot.

Comment: Maybe iPhone should be an adjective?

Answer (score 25):

A frequently used term for a feature that is incorporated into the design of something to attract attention, by appearing to make the thing significantly better, even though its actual effects on the thing's usefulness are minor, is ***gimmick***. The term is most often used for apparent technological improvements of consumer products, that are intended to impress the potential buyers, and so increase the sales, but it can be used in other contexts as well.

Comment: While gimmick may be used with with new stuff, it has no inherent implication of the thing being new

Comment: "gimmick" does not imply the thing is new, but it still a good match

Answer (score 19):

The word [newfangled](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/newfangled) seems to be what you're looking for

> recently made for the first time, but not always an improvement on what existed before

Other [definitions](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/newfangled) include

> New and often needlessly novel.

As can be seen, this word is often used in a negative sense, to imply that something is needlessly innovative, with no improvement, and possibly a worse result, which appears to be the meaning you're trying to convey.

> car manufacturers are putting *newfangled* displays in place of dashboards, but those displays still show ...

Comment: My grandfather used to use that word quite a bit, but then, we still had to use an outhouse when we visited the farm.

Comment: @Cascabel I know what you mean "newfangledness" is often in the mind of the speaker.

Comment: This would be similar to _fandanlged_, a synonym of _fantabulous_. Get your hands on this new _fan-dangled_ device. All are suggesting over the top or outrageous praise to something that on its own merits would not actually deserve them. As a sales and marketing device the exagerated nature of the words itself is to distract you from the object's actual worth.

Comment: The first 2 uses I found of this word were *positive* -- a newfangled gene editing technique, and a newfangled wood. I think the word now means "old coots would shake their heads since it's so different or novel".

Answer (score 5):

Not a word but often I use the phrase "cosmetic upgrade" to describe such things, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the word "**[fad](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fad)**" because that is really what such things are. They are (temporarily) new and popular but will over time lose popularity. It implicitly connotes that it is unnecessary as well.

Answer (score 2):

I like the word [**disimprovement**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disimprovement). For me, it carries with it the connotation of something that was intended to be an improvement but is actually the reverse. However, my (paper) copies of *Merriam-Webster's New International* and the *Shorter Oxford* dictionaries do not distinguish it from the more general idea of *worsening*.

(Incidentally, I agree with other respondents that modern electronic dashboard displays are better than the old mechanical ones and not an example of disimprovement.)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the word "novelty" what we are searching for. Isn't it exactly this?

Comment: Why would it be? An explanation and a dictionary reference would improve this answer.

Comment: novelty. Sorry I need to learn how to format my contributions better. This is the definition on a google search. I think the first part covers the newness, the second the triviality or non necessariness ( unnecessariness is a word according to inline spell check but the positive isn't perhaps there's another discussion there).

1. the quality of being new, original, or unusual.
"the novelty of being a married woman wore off"
2. a small and inexpensive toy or ornament.
"he bought chocolate novelties to decorate the Christmas tree"

Comment: I'm not sure that the example is great either. Digital speedo/tachometer are are far more tamper proof than old mechanical dials. Other advantages may be that they could use different colour display schemes (some people are colour blind etc). Another possible advantage is that as a screen is being used to display the information that same screen space could be used to display other information situationally. So, this particular innovation is, I think, more than just a novelty (which incidentally is my suggestion for the word you seek).

Answer (score 0):

The word we use at work is contrivance.  But that word seems contrived...

Comment: Including a authoritative dictionary definition/link for you r word would improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The word “overengineered” can be used for this purpose, although it doesn’t necessarily imply that the new product is based on an older one. That said, the notorious Juicero was designed to replace juicers, but it was widely panned as an overengineered product because it was an expensive and complicated piece of equipment that did nothing you couldn’t already do with your barehands.

Answer (score -1):

Such features not necessarily enhancing functionality are usually added for decorative value and are called ***embellishments*** and when they are considered completely unnecessary, they are called ***frills*** (perhaps more widely used in the form "***no-frills**" or "**no frills***").
Incidentally, the second example under the definition of ***frill*** below closely matches your own example.

Lexico:

> **[embellishment](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/embellishment)**
> *NOUN*
> **1** A decorative detail or feature added to something to make it more attractive.
>
> ‘architectural embellishments’
>
> **[frill](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/frill)**
> *NOUN*
> **2** (usually frills) An unnecessary extra feature or embellishment.
>
> ‘it was just a comfortable apartment with no frills’
>
> However, thanks to its extra frills like a high-resolution screen and
> the camera, it retails at a steep price of $999.’
>
> **[no-frills](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/no-frills)**
> *ADJECTIVE*
> [attributive] Without unnecessary extras, especially ones for decoration or additional comfort.
>
> ‘cheap fast food in no-frills surroundings’

Comment: I suggest all of that is a matter of opinion, including all the citations.

Who thinks high-resolution screens and cameras are "frills" might ask a few users…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, that's most likely an outdated example. That still doesn't make it wrong. There was another example provided too. I find it amusing that an old dictionary entry led to a downvote of the answer. Whatever floats your boat!

Comment: That's still all a matter of opinion; it's up to you not to choose outdated examples and here, dating seems to make no difference to right or wrong. I find it amusing you thought it was an old dictionary entry that led to your downvote… Still, if you float your boat with the sea-cocks open, what d'you expect?

Comment: Yesterday's frills may be today's necessities. Good luck with condemning all old publications mentioning such "frills". And good luck wishing that all boats with older designs around you don't deserve to exist. May be it's a matter of opinion! Peace!

Comment: May be it's a matter of opinion… now, where have we heard that before?

Answer (score -3):

A concept that fits your example is a [skeuomorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph), though not necessarily the shade of meaning of not being an improvement - for example, it applies to the icon for most email programs being a picture of a physical envelope, and for many use cases email is better than physical mail.

> A skeuomorph is a derivative object that retains ornamental design cues (attributes) from structures that were inherent to the original.
> Examples include pottery embellished with imitation rivets reminiscent of similar pots made of metal and a software calendar that imitates the appearance of binding on a paper desk calendar.

(I linked to wikipedia rather than an authoritative dictionary as dictionaries don't tend to have as useful examples, e.g. [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skeuomorph) just has 'an ornament or design representing a utensil or implement' which doesn't correspond much to how the term is used in the design community)

Comment: You're suggesting a metaphorical broadening of a virtually unknown word!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'skeuomorphic design' is fairly commonly used when talking about user interface design, and I"ve also come across the word once or twice in the archaeological context of patterns on pottery to make it look like basketware. The dictionary definition doesn't seem to correspond well with how it is used in either context.

Comment: In any case, OP is asking for a word with a far broader definition; the example given was not representative of all such newfangled refinements. And skeuomorphs may actually be better than the originals (pottery doesn't rust).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the pottery itself isn't the skeuomorphism, it's the decoration on it to make it look like basketware, or bronze pots (neither of which rust either). Even the OP's example is better - graphics based dials are both easier to read in multiple light levels, more responsive, and often more reliable - it is just the old-fashioned appearance which is being complained about.

Comment: I'm happy to learn this word, though it's likely not the right one for this use.

Comment: '[**skeuomorph** [noun]
an **object** or feature which imitates the design of a similar artifact made from another material.
"the pottery box with a square lid is a skeuomorph of a twilled basketry container" ' [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/skeuomorph); bolding mine]

Comment: Based on OP's example, this is IMO a fairly good fit, although it lacks the "pointless" aspect of OP's question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough - do you know where  that quote actually comes from? I've only ever heard it used as a noun for the feature, not the object as a whole.

Comment: @alephzero << A skeuomorph is a derivative object that retains ornamental design cues from structures that were inherent to the original.>> [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph)] Far narrower **and** less precise than 'a replacement device (perhaps looking nothing like the original) that should be an improvement on an existing one ... but isn't'.

Answer (score -5):

No, broadly, there is not. Sadly no-one can Post examples of something that is not.

If there were such a term, the Posted example would miss it by a long way.

Car manufacturers put - presumably you mean digital - displays in place of dashboards and those displays still show two round dials for speedometer and tachometer but by no means is the difference "only" that they're shown on screen rather than mechanically.

Here, it matters not, but if you're interested in instrumentation design why not launch a new Question elsewhere on SE?